# Diferent viewport in Vutify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

After I customize the breakpoints in the variables file. The system for some reason uses different viewport for media requests. In some classes it uses a custom viewport and in others it uses the default one. Why is this happening and what can be done to fix it?

my tag

```
<v-toolbar-items class="hidden-lg-only d-lg-none">
```

**one viewport 750px (custom)**

```
@media (min-width: 750px)
<style>
.v-application .d-lg-none {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**another viewport 1903px (default)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1903px) and (min-width: 1264px)
<style>
.v-application .hidden-lg-only {
    display: none !important;
```

[Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyjB0.png)

Comment: where is your css? is one viewport css scoped?

Comment: @depperm . I just added a photo to the question

Comment: that photo doesn't help. In your code where is the css?

Comment: @depperm I use vue + vuetify. Tag v-toolbar-item in vue component. If you don't understand this photo, you can't help me.